# Scala IDE, import project from Maven and proper Scala bundle version selection

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

This is my Maven pom.xml for Scala Spark project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>

        <spark.version>2.3.2</spark.version>

        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.4.6</scala-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.0.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.4</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Everything works fine except one thing - after the import of the project (as existing Maven project) into Scala Eclipse IDE in order to properly compile the project I have to manually go to project Properties in my Scala Eclipse IDE -> Scala Compiler and select `Latest 2.11 bundle (dynamic)` because by default `Latest 2.12 bundle (dynamic)` is selected.

Please advise how to properly configure my pom.xml in order to tell Scala Eclipse IDE to automatically use `Latest 2.11 bundle (dynamic)` after the import without any manual intervention. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this property block in your pom

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <spark.scala.version>2.11</spark.scala.version>
        <spark.version>2.2.0</spark.version>
    </properties>
```

also add this block in your dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You will get a compiler of Scala version 2.11 in Scala IDE